# Is there a WPF-equivalent to UWP's SplitView Hamburger Menu?

Tags: .net, wpf, uwp

The [Hamburger-style SplitView control](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2015/04/implementing-hamburger-button-with.html) in the Universal Windows Platform is perfect, IMO. However, my project has a WPF frontend.

Does anybody know of a WPF equivalent to this (preferably open source)?

Comment: Material Design In XAML Toolkit and MahApps have similar (Drawer and Flyout respectively) http://materialdesigninxaml.net or http://mahapps.com/   ...both of which are open source.

Comment: The same hamburger menu available on GitHub [check this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=InVsajohErQ)

Comment: @JamesWillock have you seen any sample implementations of this, the default Drawer and Flyout seem like they will still take a bit work to make it look right

Comment: @Sender that video seems to refer to UWP, not WPF.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Another implementation to study is https://github.com/alicanerdogan/HamburgerMenu

[image]

Answer (score 9):

There is really nice one in [MahappsMetro](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro) now

[image: hamburger image]

Comment: HamburgerMenu, https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/tree/develop/src/MahApps.Metro/Controls/HamburgerMenu

Answer (score 5):

Using the **GridSplitter** control and a **StoryBoard**, you can set this up quite easily. You may need to tweak this code a bit to make it appear like the hamburger, but this should get you well on your way.

```
<UserControl
x:Class="Namespace.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
x:Name="mainPage">

<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Name="CloseLeft">
            <DoubleAnimation x:Name="animNavLinksClose"
                             Storyboard.TargetName="mainPage" Storyboard.TargetProperty="NavLinksWidth"
                             To="0.0" Duration="00:00:00.2" />
        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard x:Name="OpenLeft">
            <DoubleAnimation x:Name="animNavLinksOpen"
                             Storyboard.TargetName="mainPage" Storyboard.TargetProperty="NavLinksWidth"
                             From="0" To="170" Duration="00:00:00.2" />
        </Storyboard>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="170" x:Name="NavLinksColumn" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid x:Name="grdNavLinks" Grid.Column="0">
        <!-- Navigation Buttons -->
    </Grid>

    <GridSplitter x:Name="spltNavLinks" Grid.Column="1" />

    <Grid x:Name="contentSection" Grid.Column="2">
        <!-- Content or Frame -->
    </Grid>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Then you can call your storyboard from the code-behind like this

```
// Begin Opening Animation
OpenLeft.Begin();

// Begin Closing Animation
CloseLeft.Begin();
```

Comment: I haven't tried this out yet, but would this support UWP's CompactOverlay option for the DisplayMode property, where when expanded it will show text as an overlay, and when collapsed, will show just the icons?

Comment: No, you would need to implement your own custom control for that which contains its own logic for the CompactOverlay. I am not aware of anything like that for WPF.

Try searching online for Silverlight or WinPhone7/8 examples that may port easily to WPF.